# iOS a Very Amazing(malloc_error_break)

Tags: ios

**first this my code**

```
#pragma pack (4)
typedef struct _Login{
char user[32];
char pwd[32];
int userID;
}Login,*PLogin;

const unsigned long MSG_TAG_HEADER_YXHY = 0x59485859;

#pragma pack (2)

typedef struct tagTcpPacketHeader
{
    int     ulHtag;
    char    ucVersion;
    char    ucCmd;
    int     ulUserId;
    short   usPacketNum; 
    int     ulDataLen; 
}TcpPacketHeader,*LPTcpPacketHeader;
#pragma pack ()

const unsigned int TCP_HEADER_PACKET_LEN  = sizeof(TcpPacketHeader);

- (NSData*)sendDataFileWithUserId:(const int)nUserId nCmd:(const int)nCmd pData:(NSData*)data{

    NSData* sendData;
    void* sendObj = malloc(data.length);
    [data getBytes:sendObj length:data.length];
    static int nPacketNum = 0;
    int nLen = (int)data.length + TCP_HEADER_PACKET_LEN;
    char *pTmpBuf = malloc(nLen);
    LPTcpPacketHeader tcpHeader = (LPTcpPacketHeader)pTmpBuf;
    tcpHeader->ulHtag = MSG_TAG_HEADER_YXHY;
    tcpHeader->ucVersion = 1;
    tcpHeader->ucCmd = nCmd;
    tcpHeader->ulUserId = nUserId;
    tcpHeader->usPacketNum = nPacketNum;
    tcpHeader->ulDataLen = nLen;
    memcpy(tcpHeader + TCP_HEADER_PACKET_LEN,sendObj, data.length);
    sendData = [NSData dataWithBytes:pTmpBuf length:nLen];
    nPacketNum++;
    free(pTmpBuf);
    free(sendObj);
    return sendData;
}

- (NSData*)get_File_Login:(NSString*)userID{
    int length = sizeof(Login);
    Login log_in = {"123","456",userID.intValue};
    NSData* login_data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&log_in length:length];
    NSData* ret = [self sendDataFileWithUserId:log_in.userID nCmd:5 pData:login_data];
    return ret;  
}
```

**Use**

```
NSData* ms = [self get_File_Login:@"123"];
    NSLog(@"%@",ms);
```

**After frequent use can be a problem**

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcScJ.png)

This question makes me very headache why appear “ **set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug** ”
I have added the "malloc_error_break" the breakpoint,But it doesn't work......
Who can tell me the answer？？？

Comment: Change the memcpy to use `pTmpBuf` and not `tcpHeader` as the pointer, does it help?

Comment: The problem is solved, it is the type of question, thank you very much! ｂ（￣▽￣）ｄ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the pointer in memcpy this way

```
memcpy(tcpHeader + TCP_HEADER_PACKET_LEN,sendObj, data.length);
```

this means that you want to copy into memory location pointed by `tcpHeader` plus `TCP_HEADER_PACKET_LEN` *times the size of the data the pointer points to*. It is the same as doing `&tcpHeader[TCP_HEADER_PACKET_LEN]`.

Assuming you want to write to a location right after the header there are two ways to fix it:

1) use a pointer with a size of 1, meaning a `char*`. In your code you have a pointer `pTmpBuf` that is such so just change the code to:

```
memcpy(pTmpBuf + TCP_HEADER_PACKET_LEN, sendObj, data.length);
```

2) use the size 1 for this calculation. Since the size of the data it points to is the same as `TCP_HEADER_PACKET_LEN` then multiplying it by one gives the correct location:

```
memcpy(tcpHeader + 1, sendObj, data.length);
```

I would recommend the first since it's clear what you are calculating. In the second it is unclear why you would add one, as well as using a pointer to one type when copying data that isn't that type.